# C# Auto Saving Mp3 into a Spechfic file whilst ignoring the Prompt pop up

Tags: c#, wpf

I am not good with these programming terminologies as i am still new. But i have this code:

```
 private void _btnSpeak_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(this._translationSpeakUrl))
        {
            new WebBrowser().Navigate(this._translationSpeakUrl);
        }
    }
```

_translationspeakurl is the link to google's listen function "https://translate.googleapis.com/translate_tts?ie=UTF-8&q={0}&tl={1}&total=1&idx=0&textlen={2}&client=gtx"

I do not want the prompt window asking Open/Save when the button is pressed but instead auto save it in a folder as an mp3.

Codes taken from : "https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12711/Google-Translator"

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebClient` and use `.DownloadFile()`, or you can use `HttpClient`....or you can use `URLMon` based APIs (which can "use" any session that been established by your `WebBrowser`)

Here are the differences between the two.

- [Need help deciding between HttpClient and WebClient](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20530152/need-help-deciding-between-httpclient-and-webclient)

WebClient:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ez801hhe(v=vs.110).aspx
- [suppress save/dialog in web browser and automate the download](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8597407/suppress-save-dialog-in-web-browser-and-automate-the-download)

HttpClient:

- https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.http.httpclient(v=vs.118).aspx

URLMon style:

- [The notorious yet unaswered issue of downloading a file when windows security is required](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19024794/the-notorious-yet-unaswered-issue-of-downloading-a-file-when-windows-security-is/19025793#19025793)

If you have issues downloading via that HTTPS url, then you may need to select the TLS/SSL protocol to be used/preferred.

- [Download file from HTTPS url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38986431/download-file-from-https-url)